# Cannot resolve setScreen() method

Tags: libgdx

I'm not new to libgdx, but when i ended up with my previous university project, and started new one, Android studio or IDEA cannot resolve setScreen method, other stuff works fine. Any ideas ? Hope for help. (project absolutely clear).

Comment: Could you show us the code that is giving you this error as this could be anything from a syntax error to missing source files.

Comment: It's just empty project. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a project in LibGdx gives you your core file which implements the `ApplicationListener`.

What I gather you are referring to is extending the `Game` class with with you set `Screen` classes with.

With the `ApplicationListener`.

```
public class HelloWorld implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;

    @Override
    public void create() {        
        batch = new SpriteBatch();    
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {        
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "Hello World", 200, 200);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

What you're after: (taken from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game)

```
public class Drop extends Game {

    public SpriteBatch batch;
    public BitmapFont font;

    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        //Use LibGDX's default Arial font.
        font = new BitmapFont();
        this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    }

    public void render() {
        super.render(); //important!
    }

    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

}
```

Which allows you to change screens whenever you need:

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

    final Drop game;

    OrthographicCamera camera;

    public MainMenuScreen(final Drop game) {
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

    }


        //...Rest of class omitted for succinctness.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For default, gdx main Class will extends ApplicationAdapter, you need extends Game class for get use of setScreen()