# How do I switch from my menu to my 3D FPS setup? (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm currently practising and coding a simple menu that can switch to the main game by the press of a button.

The main game is in 3D using all the features that libGDX uses to create a 3D environment. The menu is built using a Stage. I built the Menu and Render/FirstPerson classes separately to ensure they work by themselves and sure enough they did.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.mygdx.game.FPSSystem;
import com.mygdx.game.RenderingSystem;

public class MainCoreLoop extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public MenuSystem menuSystem;
    public RenderingSystem renderingSystem;
    public FPSSystem fpsSystem;

    public boolean isGameOn;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        renderingSystem = new RenderingSystem();
        fpsSystem = new FPSSystem();
        menuSystem = new MenuSystem();

        renderingSystem.create();
        fpsSystem.create();
        menuSystem.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void render () {
        isGameOn = true;

        if (MenuSystem.isMenuClosed == true) {
            isGameOn = true;
        }

        else if(isGameOn == false) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 255, 0, 0);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


            menuSystem.render();
        }

        if(isGameOn == true) { 
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 0, 0, 0);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            fpsSystem.render();
            renderingSystem.render();


            }

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        menuSystem.dispose();
        fpsSystem.dispose();
        renderingSystem.dispose();

    }

}
```

I have a RenderingSystem class that handles rendering, a FirstPersonSystem class that initialises another class, FPSCameraController class, that controls the logic and the input, which the code borrows from the FirstPersonCameraController class that comes with libGDX.

So I could test these classes together, I used a boolean named isGameOn that works well enough. After a little while of testing and refactoring, I managed to get everything to work EXCEPT the input. A 3D box renders perfectly after pressing 'New Game' but the input does not work. If I change the boolean to true, it will render the box but still with no input.

The code seems to work independently but trying to bring them together is a bit trickier to me.

I'm thinking that this might be a code order problem, but I'm quite stumped. I am new to libGDX, and I have only really been working in Java seriously for a little while, off and on in the past, so my fundamentals of code may be stopping me from figuring this out.

The rest of the code is on github [Here](https://github.com/winnieTheWind/3DGameAndMenuTest)

Any help\insight\insults would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [answered one problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282919/2979092) about using `Game` and `Screen` classes in LibGdx to make switching better which is likely to help in your circumstances.

The [Game/Screen tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game) which that snippet comes uses `Gdx.input.` methods for mouse, keyboard and touch events.

The rest should be fairly straightforward from there.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Much appreciated my friend. This is where I left off. https://github.com/winnieTheWind/Simple3DGameTestAndMenu